# select random email from array for mailable Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to test a comamnd with a mailable service for Laravel, however, I want to test it live with live data but not send out to the emails coming in.  Id like to create an array of emails where `Mail::to()` picks at random and sends it with the data.

this is my foreach.  right now is sending base on the email inside the parameters is receiving.

```
foreach ($emails as $key => $email){var_dump( $key);
    try {
        $location = Location::whereName($email->Location)->first();
        Mail::to($email->Email)->send(new NewPatientWelcome($apptRequest, $email, $location));
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        continue;
    }

}
```

This is what I have as an array

```
$emails = array();
$emails[0]->Email = 'random1@gmail.com';
$emails[0]->Email = 'random2@gmail.com';
$emails[0]->Email = 'random3@gmail.com';
$emails[0]->Email = 'random4@gmail.com';
```

thoughts?

Comment: If you're assigning `$emails[0]->Email` each time, you only have an Array of a single Email since you're repeating `[0]` (the Array index) 4 times... Why not just `$emails = ['Email' => 'random1@gmail.com', 'Email' => 'random2@gmail.com', ...]`, or a `for()` loop, etc. Also, did you do a search for "Select random element from Array PHP"? There are plenty of ways to do this... Laravel even has a Collection class with a `->random()` method to do this for you: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/collections#method-random.

Comment: @TimLewis awesome, I like the collection that laravel provides, I appreciate your help

Comment: Yeah, the `Collection` class is basically an Array with extra functionality, and, if you need the array, just do `->toArray()`. By default, Laravel uses a `Collection` for almost everything, i.e. `Model::get()` returns a `Collection`, so if you can use em, I'd recommend doing so for consistency's sake 

Answer (score 0):

You dont need `Mail` class to do it, simply do it beforehand.

if you have array of emails you can do `shuffle($emailsArray)` and then loop with foreach.

if you get your data from database, you can

`YourModel::inRandomOrder()->limit(10)->get();`

or

`YourModel::orderBy(DB::raw('RAND()'))->limit(10)->get();`

please keep in mind that selecing from DB by rand sometimes is not very opimized.